# Problem in solving a question of number theory.

Tags: number-theory

The question is :
If $n$ be a six digit number formed by the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$ such that $n$ is divisible by $5$, then what are the possible remainders if $n$ is divided by $45$.
Now,since $n$ is divisible by $5$ so it must end with $5$ and the remaining five numbers can be arranged in $5!$ ways in five different positions.Now,the important thing that I observe is that most of the numbers leave the remainder $30$ when they are divided by $45$. I use the word 'most' as I have not checked all such numbers.But I don't find suitable reason behind it.Do all these numbers belong to the same remainder class which is $30$. If the answer is 'Yes' then can anybody explain me the actual reason behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any integer $n$, we know that $n$ is congruent $\pmod 9$ to the sum of its digits.  In your case, that means that all of your numbers are $3\pmod 9$.  As they are all $0 \pmod 5$ we see, by inspection (or the Chinese Remainder Theorem) that they are all $30 \pmod {45}$.